# c++ convert integer to 8 char hex, drop the first two char so that it is only a 6 char hex, and convert back to an integer

Tags: c++, string, integer, hex, data-conversion

I have been searching and experimenting for many, many, hours now, and so far I have not been able to adapt any of the solutions I have come across to do what I want.

My goal is to take an integer (538214658) and convert it into an 8 character hex string (020148102).  Then I want to drop the first two characters (0148102) and convert it back into an integer(1343746) which I am using as a key in a map array.

The solutions I've seen so far just convert an integer into hex string, but don't take into account the desired digit length.

I am able to print out just the first 6 characters using the following code:

```
Console_Print("%06X", form ? form->refID : 0)
```

So I thought that maybe I could use that technique to store it into a string, and then use iostream or sstream to convert it back to an integer, but none of my searches turned up anything I could use.  And all of my experiments have failed.

Some help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:  Below is my solution based on Klaus' suggestion:

```
uint32_t GetCoreRefID(TESForm* form)
{
    uint32_t iCoreRefID = 0;
    if (form)
    {
        uint32_t iRefID = (uint32_t)(form->refID);
        iCoreRefID = iRefID & 0x00ffffff;
    }
    return iCoreRefID;
}
```

Comment: As in your first suggestion you can also write it in a short like: `return form?0x00ffffff & (form->refID):0`. I have no idea which type is form->refID, but it should work without an additional cast. But that did not mean that a like this `?` operator :-) You solution is much easier to read and the compiler will generate the same code I believe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need to convert to a string representation.

Look the following example:

```
int main()
{
    uint32_t val = 538214658 & 0x00ffffff;
    std::cout << std::hex << val << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::dec << val << std::endl;

}
```

You have to learn that a value is still only a value and is not dependent on the representation like decimal or hex. The value stored in a memory area or a register is still the same.

As you can see in the given example I wrote your decimal value representation and remove the first two hexadecimal digits simply by do a `bitwise and` operation with the hexadecimal representation of a mask.

Furthermore you have to understand that the printing with cout in two different "modes" did not change the value at all and also not the internal representation. With `std::dec` and `std::hex` you tell the ostream object how to create a string from an int representation.

Comment: Nice answer. In the context of this Q, it will good to collect these values into `std::stringstream`, so that using `.str()` it can be utilized for future use in form of `std::string`.

Comment: For my understanding there is no "future use" for any string because the target of the OP is to use the value as key for a map.

Comment: Actually, `std::dec/std::hex` is supported with `operator<<`. Now for that, we can use either `std::cout` object or any `std::stringstream` objects. If `std::cout` is used, then the value will be simply printed on the console and though we can see it, but cannot use it. However, if `stringstream` is used, then using its object's `.str()` method, the value can be used for any (future) purpose. My assumption is that, OP probably doesn't know that how to collect the value so that it can be used for map key. [Demo](http://ideone.com/fnxsyr). Further casted `std::stoi()` can be used to revert back.

Comment: I got your point. But it sounds for a solution for a xy problem. The OP tried to use a int->string->int conversion which is not needed. Your comment explains how the string part can be done. My answer removes the xy solution via string at all because it is not needed. That's all. If the question goes for string conversion you are right. Maybe I have not understood the question so your solution fits OPs need. I don't know.

Comment: Klaus, I will update my OP to demonstrate my understanding of your solution.